# Issue with button icons, Java 8-Queens puzzle

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, icons, jbutton

The problem I am running into is this: I have a grid of buttons in a JPanel, these buttons are supposed to change to an image of a queen when I click them. The code looks like this:

```
private Component createButtonBlack() {
    final JButton button = new BoardButton();
    final ImageIcon queen = new ImageIcon("/images/queen.png");

    button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));

    class QueenClick implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            button.setIcon(queen); 
            button.repaint();
        }
    } // end QueenClick

    ActionListener queenClicker = new QueenClick();
    button.addActionListener(queenClicker);
    return button;
} // end createButtonBlack
```

The problem (image not appearing) occurs on both the methods for creating black and white buttons but the methods are the same except for the color. Ideally I would like to be able to un-click the buttons and the image disappears but I do not know how to do that.

I am having difficulty with other parts of my 8queens GUI based problem so if you have any suggestions let me know!

Also if you need more code I will certainly supply it. Thank you.

Comment: "The problem occurs on both the methods for creating black and white buttons but the methods are the same except for the color."

_Which_ problem?

Comment: @Ray The fact that when I click my button, regardless of color, the image of a queen does not show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State the exact problem when asking a question.

> These buttons are supposed to change to an image of a queen when I click them.

So I'm guessing the icon doesn't change?

Did you:

1. Verify the ActionListener code is executed?
2. Verify the Icon was read properly?

You can easily add a System.out.println(...) to verify both of the above.

```
final ImageIcon queen = new ImageIcon("/images/queen.png");
```

I'm guessing the problem is the leading "/" in the path. The "/" tells the file system to look at the root of the drive.

> if you have any suggestions let me know!

There is no need to create two methods. You can just do:

```
Component button = createButton();
button.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
```

There is no need to create individual ActionListeners. You can create a single generic listener with code like:

```
ActionListener queenClicker = new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(Action Event e)
    {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        button.setIcon( queen );
        //button.repaint(); // not needed the setIcon method will do the repaint()
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my post. See edits. The"/" does not make a difference I have tried both ways during debugging. Thanks for your input.

Comment: The "/" does make a difference for me using JDK7 on Windows 7. Where is the debug code you added to determine id the Icon is null or not? `if you need more code I will certainly supply it` Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. That is create a simple text frame with a JButton. When you click the button the icon should be added to the button. It will take 20 lines of code to text the `concept` of writing an ActionListener that will add an Icon to a button. We don't care about the real application, its the basic concept that is important.

Comment: I have resolved the issue. Thanks. I'm sorry I wasted your time. Not very familiar with java just trying to complete a homework problem... contributions appreciated though. @camickr